# How would it look like when the Human Empire and the Monster Empire are forced to work together, but it is still peace?

Tags: society

So I have generic fantasy Human Empire, relatively Good folks, but mostly Orderly. Racially mostly homogeneous, some elves and dwarves are present, but 99% humans. And there is the Monster Empire, which is ruled by dragons, but has all kinds of naturally Evil monsters (and by Evil I mean DnD like alignments, so tangible Evil), from goblinoids to ogres and whatnot.
Pre-Threat the two sides were in equilibrium: the monsters were never united enough to pose a significant threat to the otherwise also quite powerful Human Empire (lots of magic users and a strong army + various paramilitaristic organizations), and the Monster Empire is located in a hard to pass terrain, so a formal army's movements are extremely hindered. The monsters range from threat to only unskilled or old/wounded/ill/children to the mentioned dragons, which pose a significant threat to whole groups, though not unbeatable by any means.
Border skirmishes were regular before the alliance.

They both got undeniable proof that there is some Generic Threat that threatens the very existence of the world, and the lead dragon bands together with the Human King to stand togetherish against the threat.

The world is a band of land from west to east, bound by mountains and waters. Monster Empire is to the west, Human Empire is in the middle, and the Threat comes from the east.

The thing is, the threat is yet to materialize.
What are some key points I would have to keep in mind when thinking about this? I would imagine the dragon would keep a sizable force in Human Empire, because of logistics, if the threat arrives (and they have no clear idea of how long it will take from the first actual sign to the invasion), they have to be there.
So right now, there is a whole family of dragons (Evil, macho, aggressive), a good number of giant sized creatures (ogres, trolls, actual giants) and a sizable array of smaller goblionoids, orcs, kobolds and other cannon fodder.

Is there any kind of historical reference for this? That might be a good basis for it, sans the Evil monsters part.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. Are you asking for historical reference of dragons and goblins fighting on the same side of humans?

Comment: Since the Monster Empire is Evil and **behind** the Humans, it's very possible that they'd let the humans bleed the Threat down to a manageable size while the Threat wipes out the Human Empire.  This would allow the Monsters to defeat the Threat and then take land where the Humans lived.

Comment: @RonJohn well they already formed a pact because they considered the Threat big enough that separately they both'll die. It's a different matter that it might be a ruse from the Dragon because it needs access to some resource, but on the surface they are both cooperative, so the Dragon has to keep up appearances at least. There is a lot of mistrust going around.

Comment: @L.Dutch if you phrase it that way, it sounds silly for sure. I meant more like a situation where two, supposedly hostile powers are working together, plus dragons.

Comment: Nice but very broad question. Can you elaborate on the meaning of "Evil monsters" (edit the question please)? Are you looking for a a side that's considered more powerful (like dragons and orges) and is alien/strange to the existing populace? A side that only a war would seem to give a good reason to have relations with?

Comment: An historical reference for enemies working together against a common threat ?  You could practically pick a random war in history and find stuff going on like this behind the scenes.  Way too broad.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  You're asking what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions), which isn't a good fit for our site.  Please review these links and help us by improving your question.

Comment: Here's the thing one person's crazy is another's logical, ditto "good" and "evil" and any other pair of polar opposites you can think of so answers to this question are going to be based in, if not wholly composed of, personal opinion rather than any concrete facts.

Comment: @Ash I particularly highlighted that I use DnD alignments, where good and evil are not metaphorical concepts but almost tangible elements of a character and they are quite well defined.

Comment: @MartinS. Those alignments only work as part of the defining apparatus of a magical universe, without the magic tag anything from DnD is a non-starter.

Comment: @Ash well, it IS DnD. I'm a DM. I got to this situation, then ordered a break and a time jump. I want to know how the Empire should look like after a half a year of non-occupational shared living with monsters. How an average peasant's day changes? How the military should handle incidents (since these are Evil monsters, with capital E)? I don't see how this is high concept, this is a very concrete situation, although rather left vague to not constrict thinking and not be too specific. I just want to think things through before jumping back into the campaign, how the world looks right now.

Comment: @MartinS. Then tag the question appropriately, because at the moment it isn't. Also you need to make very clear in the question that you wish to deal with moral absolutes because you haven't thus my POB VTC.

Comment: @Ash This is already in the text: "and by Evil I mean DnD like alignments, so tangible Evil". What more can you expect? And there is no DnD or morality tag, whatever that would be.

Comment: DnD alignments are [tag:magic]. I've experienced tangible evil, tangible evil being evil you can feel, but that's a judgement call not a moral absolute, the person in question still felt they were in the right, in the real world, where only having the [tag:society] leaves us, there are no moral absolutes everything is relative.

Answer (score 3):

### The US and Britain worked with the USSR in WW2.

It's not exactly like your scenario, though, since the US+Britain and USSR made Germany fight a three-front war whereas your scenario is a one-front war.

More importantly, there were people in US+Britain who were deluded into thinking that the USSR was a Workers Paradise.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder, were there instances when there was peace and the two sides were in the same position? Probably not before the end of the war, but after, before the Cold War started to form with the USSR becoming openly hostile. Should I look up post war, pre divide Berlin (not an easy Google I assure you)?

Comment: Three way alliance did not make Germany do anything except, ultimately, lose.  Germany chose the 3 front war.  USSR had a pact with Germany and was very happy to sit on the sidelines and watch Germany and western powers slug it out.   Google Operation Barbarosa -  for reasons historians still debate, the Germans attacked the USSR before Germany had finished with Europe.  One can make a strong case that in doing so they bit off more than they could chew.

Comment: @Willk the Germans never left Europe when invading the USSR.

Comment: @AlexP - a little help here?

Comment: @Willk help with what?  The Asian-European border is at the Ural mountains and Caspian Sea.  Germany never got that far.  (It's true that they bit off more than they could chew, but that's irrelevant to the Answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Continued from my comment...

There's a TV show running just now, "Britannia", that tells a story (a story expanded and exaggerated for the sake of romance/theatrics) of the second attempt of the Roman empire to invade Britain.

As the story is told (minor spoiler), **after the Romans establish a foothold, while considered to be demonic outsiders by one dominant tribe, they're still possible allies in an upcoming war against the other dominant tribe**. Both tribes are willing to "sleep with the devil" against the more hated devil they know.

This kind of thing happened and was encouraged by the Roman Empire as it made its conquests, many times.